# Find and update all windows drivers silently from a network share

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have a network share with extracted drivers (from Dell) (with .inf files).  Is there a script or program which will find and update all computer drivers from a network share (no splashy UI's, no progress bars etc..) for 500+ computers periodically?  I'm aware that I can do it one at a time using something like:

```
rundll32 syssetup,SetupInfObjectInstallAction DefaultInstall 128 path\to\file.inf
```

But that means I need to know that this specific computer of this specific model needs updating.  I know "windows update" has this ability for more generic drivers.

Comment: If you're looking for spitting out updates to 500+ computers, I'm guessing you're in an enterprise environment; in that case, ServerFault may be a better fit

Comment: HP has software called HP SSM - HP System Software Manager. It allows you to select your computer hardware and OS then lets you download the drivers and software needed for the system to a shared folder. The client then can be run on the machine to update the nessecary files. You could see if Dell does anything of the same.

Comment: I'm not sure if it supports clients in the same way as it does servers, but look at [Dell OpenManage Essentials](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/1989.openmanage-essentials.aspx).

Comment: Dell OME is for servers, not workstations, unfortunately. They have another product or suite for desktop fleet management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of software packages that install software and run scripts remotely.  I'm thinking of things like:

1. Group Policy (if you have 500+ computers, you may be in a domain, yes?)
2. Management software (I'm thinking LANdesk, Altiris Deployment Solution, etc.)
3. [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and a list of machines.

Altiris, and probably LANdesk, will let you search by the machine model, so there's that. Schedule a job based on machine model that throws driver updates.

For the other two, you would need to detect the machine model scriptomatically.  (If you wanted to download drivers direct from Dell you could maybe use something like [the Dell Driver Update Tool](http://www.drivers.com/update_dell_drivers_main.php#driversupdates) instead.)  You can do this with PowerShell using

```
Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object Manufacturer, Model
```

You could then write some conditional logic based on this--perhaps subscripts in the share that hosts the drivers?--and run this script as an group policy or PsExec script.  (Group Policy would be a lot nicer.)

For PsExec, put the PowerShell script on the share with the drivers, get a list of computers, and write a script that's basically:

```
PsExec @computerlist powershell \\path\to\yourscript.ps1
```

Or a PowerShell equivalent.  Run this as an account that's an admin on all the machines and has access to the share.

Good luck!  I hope that helps.

Comment: Your entire answer could be wrapped up into suggesting the "dell driver update tool" or write your own script.  The dell driver update tool you linked to does not run on the command line, it doesn't download drivers from a network share, the .exe doesn't have options to install silently (and FYI asking for licensing for >1 machine is a nightmare).  And as for writing my own script... well that's what I'm trying to avoid if there is another tool out there.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you told us what specific problem you were trying to solve.  As your question stands, I think most people will read it as "It's my job to maintain PCs for an organization" and will answer accordingly.  As someone who has done that job in the past, we generally include the drivers in the image and only update them if there's an issue.

Comment: It is my job to maintain PC's for an organization.  I need to test out the drivers before I can put them on the machines due to compatibility problems with other software.  So I put them into a network share after I test them.  I have software to do pushing out these drivers (AD, Landesk, Prism) but that's not what my question is about.   I have desktops and laptops which come and go so I'll never be sure what is on any machine at any one time.  I can set this installer to run when a laptop connects to the domain (specifically to the network share).  That's the backstory, but not relevant.

Comment: So, basically, you're SOLELY interested in an existing script or software package that detects machines and their current driver state and applies approved drivers only.  Yes?

Comment: correct!  I'll make one if I have to but only after I give the community a chance to respond with better suggestions than I can do alone.

Comment: It looks like such a thing exists, at least for SCCM, but I don't know about LANdesk interoperability.  http://www.altrinsicsolutions.com/edm/sccm

Comment: I can't use SCCM because the network I'm on has multicast ports blocked.  I'm waiting till they switch to IPV6.  But I'm sure it's the industry answer for this so I'm accepting this as the answer.